install influxDB in Rockylinux9, but can't use WebUI
I use docker to install rockylinux9 as container, then install influxDB in rockylinux9.
After start influxDB, I'd like to use Web UI. But it shows error.
(If I install influxDB as container, Web UI can use.)
But the point is that I need to install influxDB in rockylinux9 in docker.
Please help me to solve this problem.
The web I used：http://localhost:8086

docker run -it rockylinux:9 /bin/bash

docker run -it --name <containerName> rockylinux:9

dnf update -y

dnf install procps-ng

curl -s https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdata-archive.key | gpg --import

gpg --list-keys

curl -O https://dl.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb2-2.7.10_linux_amd64.tar.gz

echo "9cb54d3940c37a8c2a908458543e629412505cc71db55094147fd39088b99c6c  influxdb2-2.7.10_linux_amd64.tar.gz" | sha256sum --check -

curl --silent --location https://repos.influxdata.com/influxdata-archive.key | gpg --import -

curl --silent --location "https://download.influxdata.com/influxdb/releases/influxdb2-2.7.10_linux_amd64.tar.gz.asc" | gpg --verify - influxdb2-2.7.10_linux_amd64.tar.gz

tar xvfz ./influxdb2-2.7.10_linux_amd64.tar.gz

mv ./influxdb2-2.7.10/usr/bin/influxd /usr/local/bin/

influxd &


